# Null checks ruin the UI of my Blazor wasm web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5, blazor-webassembly

When I add a null check on a page, it messes with the UI, especially some of the bootstrap components of that page.

For example:

```html
@if(Summary is null){
    <Spinner />
}
else
{
    <div class="col-4">
        <label class="mr-3 col-2 mt-3">My dropdown</label>
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-select col" id="kt_form_status">
            <option value="Today">Today</option>
            <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
            <option value="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
        </select>
    </div>
}
```

displays this

[image]

and:

```html
<div class="col-4">
        <label class="mr-3 col-2 mt-3">My dropdown</label>
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-select col" id="kt_form_status">
            <option value="Today">Today</option>
            <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
            <option value="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

gives me this:

[image]

What am I missing or what can I do to stop/workaround this?

Comment: there is no missing `@` on the page. I removed other markups to have only the one in the question and I get same behaviour.

Comment: just did, they are different. I wonder why.

Comment: You wouldn't have some JS running on first render?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine no I do not. It is just plain html and some bootstrap.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `<Spinner/>` is a component that shows a loader while waiting for `Summary` to have data. It doesn't matter though, because I changed it to a text and I got same behaviour.

Comment: I created a new blazor wasm app and in the default template, there's a page named `FetchData`, in this page, it also had a null judgement, and I copied your `select` code into the `if` clause then it still had the same UI with the one in the else clause. Here I had 2 suggestions, first, you should press f12 to open console window to check if the css files are loaded successfully. The second, you should check the business logic for how you set value for `Summary`.

Comment: @IsaacIkusika it's not the null check. the only way you'd get such a difference is if some *other* code either prevented loading the stylesheets or overrode them. Post the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. Somehow, somewhere, a null `Summary` breaks the stylesheets

Comment: @IsaacIkusika does `Summary` contain a theme property? Your first image is [a typical Bootstrap select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/) which means the null check didn't change anything. The second image though shows a completely different theme. A different theme was loaded in the second case

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in my side so I created a new .net core MVC project and adding your select. unfortunately everything worked fine in my side about the UI. my idea here is that you may try to check if there's any CSS file missing loading when the UI is ruin. see the elements in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you've given us in a standard Blazor template Index page.

I've:

1. Added a button to toggle Summary from null to a value.
2. Wrapped your column divs in rows to space out correctly.

Both look the same to me.

In your images there's two different styles applied, therefore there must be something your not showing us that is causing your problem.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="m-3 p-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Update>Update</button>
</div>

@if (Summary is null)
{
    <alert class="alert alert-danger">
        Summary is Null!
    </alert>
}
else
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="mr-3 col-2 mt-3">My dropdown</label>
            <select class="form-control bootstrap-select col" id="kt_form_status">
                <option value="Today">Today</option>
                <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
                <option value="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label class="mr-3 col-2 mt-3">My dropdown</label>
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-select col" id="kt_form_status">
            <option value="Today">Today</option>
            <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
            <option value="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string? Summary;

    private void Update()
         => Summary = Summary is null ? "Not Null" : null;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Summary` in my instance is getting data from an API.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  My code above shows you that null checking doesn't change the UI.  No one can help you because the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is a property. I got data from a source and set `Summary` to the data in the "code behind". I wonder why the downvote though.

Comment: @IsaacIkusika [Polite] This question is going nowhere because you aren't providing information that's important in answering the question.  While my answer doesn't fix your problem it shows a working solution with the information you've so far provided.  I  haven't (yet) downvoted or voted to close the question to give you time to provide that information.   Null checks don't ruin UI formatting, period.